# How to avoid duplicate rendering of DOM elements in jsrender

Tags: jsrender

is it possible to check for duplicate Dom elements while rendering a jsrender.template?

For example:

1. if element doesnt exists use this:

   ```
   <li id="liv_{{:nid}}">
       <div class="qwqw"><a href="#"></a></div>
       <div class="">
           <p class="we">{{:spd}} <span>mph (todo)</span></p>
       </div>

       <div class="clear"></div>
     </li>
   ```
2. if the element "liv1" exists then update the view and dont perform step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [helper functions](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/09_helper-functions.html)

Templates pseudo code:

```
{{if ~domElementExists(id)}}
...
{{/if}}
```

Helper's pseudo code

```
$.views.helpers({

    domElementExists: function( id ) {

        return $("#liv_" + id).length > 0;

    }
});
```

Comment: But note that when jsrender code runs, the DOM has not yet been updated, so the helper is looking at the DOM prior to inserting the new JsRender output. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28351083/1054484 for example of a helper based on data, not the DOM.